Plumbing sink and washer correctly
I'm in California (https://up.codes/viewer/california/ca-plumbing-code-2022) and trying to do a reasonable job of correctly adding a washer & sink hook up in a detached garage. Currently the drain comes in through the exterior wall via a 90 long sweep elbow (i.e. it wasn't brought up thru the foundation).
Due to where the pipe comes in and my spacing, I need to have the sink on the left of the washer. This is what I've come up with after researching. Does it seem reasonable or am I way off? Is there a less dumb way to do this?
EDIT: I added some distance limits to the diagram - one thing I'm still trying to figure out is if I can or should move the washer box (and the sink) further left as it would be hidden by the washer on pedestal (About 53" high) otherwise. I'm unsure if theres any horizontal distance constraint that would prevent moving it further though.


I can't  see any obvious problems.
